# getting the part of the record Eloqouent laravel 5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

first, I have 2 models named user.php and users_details.php, the two model are in relationship and its working, I can retrieve the record from that relationship binding. Below is protected function where I put a eloqouent query for global access within the class and its inheritor.

```
protected function current_users(){
    return User::with('user_details')->first();
}
```

and I can access it using (display the result)

```
$user = $this->current_users();
dd(var_dump($user));
```

and when I tried to get the part of the retrieved record (column content in row of the retrieved record) e.g. ('college')

```
dd(var_dump($this->current_users()->college));
```

it return 'null' which supposedly its should not null (in the reference table, the column 'college' is not null). Any ideas, clues, help, suggestions, recommendations please?

Comment: Is this a hasMany or hasOne relationship? I'm also assuming college is in the user_details table?

Comment: hasOne relationship @ThomasKim

Comment: @ThomasKim: yes the college is in the users_details table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$user = $this->current_users();
```

This returns a `user` with the `user_details` relationship, but the columns in `user_details` aren't accessible at its "first" level if that makes sense. In other words, you need to access college like this:

```
{{ $user->user_details->college }}
```

Think of it kind of like a tree. At the top most level, you have the user. Then you access that user's user_details. Then, you have access to the columns of user_details.

Answer (score -1):

Remove brackets ( and ) 
Try print like this

```
$this->current_users->college
```

Update:

```
$this->current_users()->user_details->college
```

Comment: first of all, its not brackets, it is a parenthesis and the parenthesis should not be removed because im interacting with a function.

Comment: ah, i was using my mobile to answer this, it will be $this->current_users()->user_details->college You may rename it to current_user not plural